# how to make threads with continuous id's

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to assign continuous Ids for some threads when i'm creating them, and doesn't matter what starting id is (like 11, 12 , 13,..  or 9, 10, 11)

This is what i have done, here i am creating 4 threads and invoke My_function()

```
for ( byte i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
    {
     myThreadArray[i] = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(My_function));
     myThreadArray[i].Start(i);
    }
```

it seems working but can i be guaranteed that i always assign continuous id's for them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using an array to contain your threads, each sequentially assigned element of that array will have a sequential index.

However, if you need to map a Thread ID to an element in `MyThreadArray`, since you have no control over thread `ID`s when the threads are created (only the thread `Name`), you could use a `Dictionary<int, int>` to map the actual thread `ID`s to the `MyThreadArray` index

```
for ( byte i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
    {
     myThreadArray[i] = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(My_function));
     myThreadArray[i].Start(i);
     MyThreadDictionary.Add(MyThreadArray[i].ManagedThreadId(), i)
    }
```

and access it by:

```
logSet[MyThreadDictionary(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)]
```

or use `Array.FindIndex` to retrieve the index of the `MyThreadArray` element that contains the thread matching the thread ID you want to match, in much the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Name` property to your advantage here to keep track...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.name.aspx

```
for ( byte i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
{
 myThreadArray[i] = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(My_function));
 myThreadArray[i].Start(i);
 myThreadArray[i].Name = i.ToString();
}
```

You can access the current thread like so:

```
logSet[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name) % numOfThreds]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i needed to use it as array index. with something  like this logSet[(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId) % numOfThreds]

Comment: Ah, I got it now. it can use to improve my program, but i really interested can it be done as i tried

Comment: @narakaya Why aren't you storing a data structure that has the thread and the associated log (and everything else) as properties in the array? Then you could just use `threadsAndLogs.First(tal=>tal.Thread == Thread.CurrentThread).Log`.